# *(int*) a - Can somebody explain

Tags: c, pointers

Can somebody explain as simple as you can how what/how `*(int*) a` works?

As well as how in another file: (`any.h`)

```
#ifndef ANY_H
#define ANY_H

typedef void * any;

#endif
```

Code here is in another file `test.c` where `any.h` is included

```
int abcd(any j) {
   k = ((struct a*)j)->b[0]; 
}
```

works? For the `struct` one does it mean, `j` is the pointer? A little confused.

Comment: I think the `*(int*)` in your question is a little confusing given your example is a struct pointer cast, that then uses an `->`, instead of a `*` to get at pointed-to info. Also whoever wrote the `any` bit  was just making life harder for everyone.

Comment: Rather than `*(int*)` (which doesn't appear in your example), you can also write two lines `int *xp = x;` (where x is a void poiner), then `xp` is a pointer to int and `*xp` is the int

Comment: the `*(int*)` and the example are two different things, thats why i wrote "and in another file" should of made myself more clear :).  Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*(int*)a` should give you the contents of the location pointed to by `a`, while treating `a` as if it was a pointer to an integer. If `a` was already a pointer to an integer, `*(int*)a` is equivalent to `*a`. The stuff in the brackets is a cast operator.

`any` is now the equivalent of `void *`, or a generic pointer that does not refer to any specific value type. `void *` is normally used for places where you don't want to specify what a pointer is pointing to, but just identify a location in memory (with no regard to its contents). To get the value pointed to by a void pointer, you first need to cast it into a pointer to a specific type, which is what `(struct a*)j` does: treats `j` as if it was a pointer to `struct a`.

Answer (score 1):

When you type `(int*)` etc it is a `cast`. This tells the compiler to 'think' of whatever is there as that type.

Hence you are casting (telling the compiler) that `j` is a pointer to some struct a in the line `((struct a*)j)`

Might just add that if `j` isn't this type you may have strange errors runtime.